# Is $ \{x\} \times Y \cong Y$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X, Y $ are  topological spaces. Pick a point $(x,y) \in X \times Y$. I am trying to show that $\{x\} \times Y $ is homeomorphic to $Y$. Is this true?

Is this function $f(x,y) = y$ a homeomorphism? This is obviously continuous since it is projection map. But its inverse is also continuous? thanks for your help

Comment: Its inverse is continuous if and only if the two components $y \mapsto x$ and $y \mapsto y$ are continuous.

Comment: Of course it is since $\{x\}$ is just a meaningless symbol associated to $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some methods to show that the map $g:Y\to\{x\}\times Y,\ y\mapsto(x,y)$, which is the inverse of $f$, is continuous. The second one is especially useful.

- You can deal directly with the open sets. An non-empty open set in $\{x\}\times Y$ has the form $\{x\}\times U$ for all open sets $U$ in $Y.$ What is its preimage under $g$ ?
- A map from a space $Z$ to a product $\prod_{i\in I} Y_i$ is continuous iff each component is continuous. In your case $g$ has two components, one is the constant map $Y\to\{x\}$, the other is the identity on $Y$.
- If you happen to know a bit category theory, there is an elegant way: A singleton space $\{x\}$ is a *terminal object* in the category **Top**, and the product space is the categorical product. Now, in each category, the canonical map from an object to its product with the terminal object is a natural isomorphism.